# Drawing a table with vanilla JS and loops

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am doing an exercise (from Beginning Javascript) to better understand DOM manipulation. Attempting to recreate the following table in a DRY method using only JS (the textbook solution is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/robert93/99mph1jq/)):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Car</td>
        <td>Top Speed</td>
        <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Chevrolet</td>
        <td>120mph</td>
        <td>$10,000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Pontiac</td>
       <td>140mph</td>
       <td>$20,000</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I tried this but unsure how you can loop variable creation without throwing an error:

```
var array = [['Car', 'Top Speed', 'Price'],['Chevrolet', '120mph', '$10,000'], ['Pontiac', '140pmh', '$20,000']] // Creating a data array which a loop will source from

    var table = document.createElement('table');
    document.body.appendChild(table); // Drew the main table node on the document

    for (var i = 0; i<3; i++) { 
        var tr[i] = document.createElement('tr'); //Create 3 <tr> elements assigned to a unique variable BUT need a working alternative for 'tr[i]'
        table.appendChild(tr[i]); // Append to <table> node

        for (var j = 0; j<3; j++) {

            var tdText = document.createTextNode(array[i][j]); // Extract data from array to a placeholder variable
            tr[i].appendChild(tdText); // Take string from placeholder variable and append it to <tr> node
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you see when you stepped through your code with the debugger? What did you see on the console when you viewed it? See http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e3d3wxwh/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use `tr` instead of `tr[i]`. It will work

```
var array = [['Car', 'Top Speed', 'Price'],['Chevrolet', '120mph', '$10,000'], ['Pontiac', '140pmh', '$20,000']] // Creating a data array which a loop will source from

    var table = document.createElement('table');
    document.body.appendChild(table); // Drew the main table node on the document

    for (var i = 0; i<3; i++) { 
        var tr = document.createElement('tr'); //Create 3 <tr> elements assigned to a unique variable BUT need a working alternative for 'tr[i]'
        table.appendChild(tr); // Append to <table> node

        for (var j = 0; j<3; j++) {
            var tdElement = document.createElement('td');
            tdElement.innerHTML = array[i][j];
            tr.appendChild(tdElement); // Take string from placeholder variable and append it to <tr> node
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

As already said the problem is the syntax error in declaring the `tr[i]` variable.

A more cleaner way will be is to use the table api methods like

```js
var array = [
    ['Car', 'Top Speed', 'Price'],
    ['Chevrolet', '120mph', '$10,000'],
    ['Pontiac', '140pmh', '$20,000']
  ] // Creating a data array which a loop will source from

var table = document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(table); // Drew the main table node on the document

array.forEach(function(row) {
  var tr = table.insertRow(); //Create a new row

  row.forEach(function(column) {
    var td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerText = column; // Take string from placeholder variable and append it to <tr> node
  });
});
```

- [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement)
- [insertRow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)
- [insertCell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)

Answer (score 0):

My version with the use of `THead` and `TBody` as well as `th` and `td`.

```js
// input as an array
const array = [
  ['Car', 'Top Speed', 'Price'],
  ['Chevrolet', '120mph', '$10,000'],
  ['Pontiac', '140pmh', '$20,000']
]

const table = document.createElement('table');

// Generate Header
const head = table.createTHead();
const tr = head.insertRow();
array[0].forEach(function(item) {
  const th = document.createElement('th')
  th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
  tr.appendChild(th);
});

// Generate Body
const body = table.createTBody();
array.slice(1).forEach(function(row) {
  const tr = body.insertRow();
  row.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
      const th = document.createElement('th')
      th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
      tr.appendChild(th);
    } else {
      const td = tr.insertCell(); // create td only
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
    }
  });
});

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

ref:

- `<thead>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead
- `<tbody>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody
- `<th>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th